# Unable to SQL => Getting content of last 7 days

Tags: mysql

I thought I was good with SQL till I was told to get the content of all 30 days. I do have a column called "connect_time" which has date and time in the following format: 2014-08-28 11:11:42

All my queries have been a fail till now. I tried the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266130/how-to-select-last-one-week-data-from-todays-date

I just tried:

```
SELECT  *
FROM   Table_Name
WHERE  connect_time >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

I cannot understand the reason its wrong and I am trying to find the syntax so I can edit it myself but I am getting confused what part of the code is syntax and what is their column names.

Comment: I see two tags. Is this a SQL Server question or a MySQL question ???

Comment: Its mySQl thanks for pointing my mistake i meant to put just sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [**DATE_ADD() or DATE_SUB()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name
WHERE connect_time >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -7 DAY);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name
WHERE connect_time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Without those functions, you can also do

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name
WHERE connect_time >= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL -7 DAY);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name
WHERE connect_time >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Comment: Thank you it works! After hours of trying, it works. I really need to re-learn sql

Comment: You just need to learn MySQL's dialect (almost like a British citiszen speaking English in the USA, a Portuguese citizen speaking in Brazil, citizen of Spain speaking in Puerto Rico, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

This query runs just fine, but does not include entire days unless your time is set to midnight.  This is because `GETDATE()` returns date and time,so it will only return rows >= to the exact moment 7 days ago that matches the time of your query.

If you are trying for whole days, perhaps:

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.Table_Name
 WHERE connect_time >= CAST (DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())AS Date) 
    AND connect_time < CAST (GETDATE() AS Date) 
 ORDER BY connect_time
```

This would start at midnight of 7 days ago, but would not include today's partial data.

EDIT: GETDATE() is a SQL Server function.  In MySQL is would be something like:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table_Name
 WHERE connect_time >= DATE (CURDATE() INTERVAL -7 DAY) 
    AND connect_time < DATE(CURDATE()) 
 ORDER BY connect_time
```

But I am not MySQL savvy.

Comment: What if it cant recognize cast?

Comment: The OP requires the syntax for MySQL.  Yours appears to be SQL Server?

Comment: That is my mistake I put SQL-server and MySQL. I just realized i am terrible w/ database. Thanks for pointing out max.